# How to get the average of two floating point numbers

Tags: operator-overloading, operators, ocaml

I want to get the average of a 2 floating point numbers. My function for the integer variant

```ml
let int_average x y = (x + y) / 2
```

works fine but when I try to write it for floats

```ml
let float_average x y = (x +. y) / 2.
```

it fails with the error

> This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
>   int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to "floatify" the division operator. `/` should be `/.`, just as `+.` is the float variant of `+`:

```
let float_average x y = (x +. y) /. 2.
```